# Trouble enumerating an array

Tags: c, arrays, strstr

can't seem to see my error here, when I compile and run I just get the "Search for: " coming up, I enter something that should show a result but nothing happens and just exits.

I've recreated this code exactly(from what I can see!) from the Head First C book but it's not working the same, theirs appears to show the results when you search for it.

So hit me up guys, what have I done wrong? Thanks in advance!!

Btw, arrays + array pointers do my head in lol.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = 
{
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - A wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
           printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
}
}

int main()
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: ");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you type "The girl from Iwo Jima"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fgets` function, as stated [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), includes the new line (`\n`) character, since it is considered a valid character:

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

This means that you are going to check, for example:

```
"I left my heart in Harvard Med School"
```

with

```
"I left\n"
```

so the match doesn't occur. You could try using [`gets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) or replacing the `\n` character with a NUL (`\0`):

```
char search_for[80];
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

In `fgets` man page:  "Reading  stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer."   
  
 So in you code, after the final "Enter" is pressed, the value stored in `search_for` is actually "`what_you_type`"+"`\n`". But `tracks` does not contain any "`\n`", it's not surprise of not finding what you have typed in it.

Change `tracks` to:

```
 char tracks[][80] = 
 {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School\n",
    "Newark, Newark - A wonderful town\n",
    "Dancing with a Dork\n",
    "From here to maternity\n",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima\n",
};
```

and type the whole sentence or something like "`Iwo Jima`", you will definitely find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys...but it's interesting that they don't have \n in the book and their code seems to work AND they only search for a word, don't have to search for a whole sentence or anything. 

This is their code. ![screenshot of ebook page][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/X25RC.png

Comment: Maybe the book is not serious enough. If you add "`\n`" in tracks, you can find it by only entering the final word of each sentence, such as "`Jima`", "`Iwo Jima`", "`from Iwo Jima`" etc.

Comment: not serious enough? every book I've read so far has something wrong with it, what do you suggest?

Comment: try: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

Jack's answer is OK.

You can replace

> fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);

by

> scanf("%79s", search_for);

This is a erratum of the book. You can view the others at [Errata for Head First C](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920015482).